# Jquery scrollTop not working in live environment

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I'm trying to move the users view down when a button is clicked to reveal additional content. My code snippet is:

```
jQuery( ".revealcontact" ).click(function() {
  jQuery( "#ad-contact-details" ).show();
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery("#ad-contact-details").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

In a jsfiddle this works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/0zjg8dcx/ (Click the Contact Seller button)

On my live site however the same HTML and JS markup doesn't work:

http://app.commonroom.com.au/notices/entrepreneurship-small-business/

I'm at a loss for why it works in one place and not on the live site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollable element is `#main` rather than `html, body`.

Also, `offset().top` doesn't give the desired behaviour, you could try something like

```
jQuery( ".revealcontact" ).click(function() {
  jQuery( "#ad-contact-details" ).show();
  jQuery('#main').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery("#main")[0].scrollHeight
  }, 1000);
});
```